# How to merge List of Multimaps returned from executors Future with Java8

Tags: java, java-8, executorservice

Suppose I have the following snippet: (The future is result of Callable task)

```
List<Map<String, List<Offset>>> results = new ArrayList<>();

for (Future<Map<String, List<Offset>>> future : listFutures)   {
    Map<String, List<Offset>> mapResult = future.get();
    results.add(mapResult);
}
```

I want to make an aggregation of all `"Map<String, List<Offset>>"` into `flatMap` from all `Futures` together , the use case that will be is duplication key between the maps, in that case I need to add the value into the list of  `List<Offset>`

I expected after flatMap , have result of `"Map<String, List<Offset>>"`

P.S

I saw some examples but they are talking not during iteration.

```
       Stream.concat(map1.entrySet().stream(), map2.entrySet().stream())
                        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                            entry -> entry.getKey(), 
                            entry -> entry.getValue()
                        )
                    );
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: so your output should be `Map<String, List<Offset>>`?

Comment: If you have to deal with duplicates you have to manually add tose values to the value list of your result map, but that should be fairly simple or what exactly have you tried?

Comment: @ Eugene , yep exactly ---->  Map<String, List<Offset>>

Comment: how do u want to handle those that will fail via `future.get`?

Comment: @ Eugene , it is other issue , thanks , but lets assume in the beginning the happy path , and everything will pass from the future....

Comment: @ Holger  , I'm working with future ,But open for new suggestions like "CompletableFutures" ....."taking during iteration means" --> I've edited my question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I got everything right...

```
listFutures.stream()
            .map(x -> {
                try {
                    return x.get();
                } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            })
            .flatMap(x -> x.entrySet().stream())
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    Entry::getKey,
                    Entry::getValue,
                    (left, right) -> {
                        left.addAll(right);
                        return left;
                    }));
```

And may be a simpler way:

```
    for (Future<Map<String, List<Offset>>> f : listFutures) {
        Map<String, List<Offset>> inner = f.get();
        for (Entry<String, List<Offset>> e : inner.entrySet()) {
            results.merge(e.getKey(), e.getValue(), (left, right) -> {
                left.addAll(right);
                return left;
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: The `inner` variable is not necessary; you can simply loop like `for (Entry<String, List<Offset>> e: e.get())`. Or, use `f.get().forEach( (key, value) -> …`, as `map.forEach` is truly a syntactical improvement over iterating over the `.entrySet()`… Maxing it out: `listFutures.forEach(f -> f.get().forEach( (k,v) -> results.merge(k, v, (l, r) -> { l.addAll(r); return l; })));`

Comment: wow...seems right i got the results , can you explain please the last part of the "merge"....especially "results.merge(e.getKey(), e.getValue(), (left, right) -> {
                left.addAll(right);
                return left;
            });"

Comment: @VitalyT you can read the `Map#merge` documentation, basically a way to either put data in a `HashMap` or `merge` already existing data